# What am I - Sing the Alphabet song!

Tags: riddle

Give me a dollar, You start to drink
play the music, children start to sing
look at me, without a blink
like the diamond on my wedding ring

Larger than a boulder, smaller than a pingpong
the force with this one is very strong
you might wonder if you are wrong
did I mention the alphabet song?

Comment: my first thought is Karaoke machine, but it doesn't quite fit everyting

Comment: @MrSudds One of those actually got the correct answer but still missing some of the clues.  I am waiting for them before accepting as an answer =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are:

> A star

Give me a dollar, You start to drink

> Not sure about this line but after the hint in the comments, Google search for dollar drinks Canada gives results for $1 any size drinks at McDonald's, specifically mentioning Canada.  Link to my "star" theory: Canadian flag features a maple leaf, which has the shape of a star.  EDIT: Starbucks!  Alex revealed it in the comments, I missed this clue.

play the music, children start to sing

> Popular Children's song "Twinkle, Twinkle, Little Star".  Every kid will start singing it when they hear the music.

look at me, without a blink
like the diamond on my wedding ring

> "Up above the world so high, like a diamond in the sky"

Larger than a boulder, smaller than a pingpong

> MUCH larger than a boulder, but to us it looks smaller than a pingpong.

the force with this one is very strong

> The gravitational pull or "force" of the star.  (EDIT: And a reference to star wars, which I thought was just part of the clue, not part of the answer)

you might wonder if you are wrong

> "how I wonder what you are"

did I mention the alphabet song?

> The "alphabet song" has the same tune as "twinkle twinkle little star".

Comment: Hints on line 1: I am a Canadian

Comment: Also on the second last line, there's another reference

Comment: @Alex So is this the right answer?

Comment: @randal'thor this is the right answer indeed, but with line 1 still not what I am looking for.  I guess I will accept it as an answer and explain in my next comment

Comment: Line1: Starbuck   
Line4 is also a reference from Starwar

Comment: Ah, starbucks!  Makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

You're a:

> Jukebox

Because

> One dollar is usually enough to start playing the music. The ring might be a reference to vinyls. The jukebox is larger than a boulder and smaller than a ping pong table!

Comment: That was quick. I was thinking along the lines of a karaoke machine.

Comment: Nice attempt not what I am looking for, there are a couple lines didn't explained